# Grails log4j Appender not Working

Tags: grails, log4j, grails-2.5

I use Grails 2.5.6 and I try to create 2 different appender.
The first appender should log all errors.
The second appender should log all infos.
I created the appenders but its still not working.
(The log files are created correctly)

```
log4j = {
    appenders{
        appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(
            name: 'errorLog',
            threshold: Level.ERROR,
            datePattern: "'-'yyyy-mm-dd",
            file: "logs/dev/${Metadata.current.'app.name'}##${Metadata.current.'app-version'}-error.log",
            layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '%d [%t] %-5p %c{2} %x - %m%n')
        )

        appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(
            name: 'infoLog',
            threshold: Level.INFO,
            datePattern: "'-'yyyy-mm-dd",
            file: "logs/dev/${Metadata.current.'app.name'}##${Metadata.current.'app-version'}.log",
            layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '%d [%t] %-5p %c{2} %x - %m%n')      
        )

    }

    root{
        error 'errorLog'
        info 'infoLog'
    }

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried only one? Is that working?

Comment: Yes I tried to log the errors but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this causes the problem, but I noticed two things in your example:

1. The file attribute in both appenders is the same

   ```
   file: "logs/dev/${Metadata.current.'app.name'}##${Metadata.current.'app-version'}-error.log",
   ```
2. The block for the log levels is missing (see [enter link description here](http://docs.grails.org/2.5.x/guide/conf.html#logging))

   ```
   log4j = {
       error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
              'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages' //  GSP

       warn   'org.apache.catalina'
   }
   ```

Comment: 1. Ups, it was an copy error :P.
2. I have now in both logs the same info logs(its not working)

Comment: Can you specify what you mean with 'its not working'?
Do you mean that the log files are created but nothing is logged?

Comment: Yes sir. The log files are created but both are empty

Comment: What about my second point: a definition which namespaces/packages should be logged at which level?

Comment: the error log file should log all Level.Error and the info log file all Level.Info